# How does a mandatory voting system affect the outcome of elections?

Tags: voting, political-theory, voting-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages/disadvantages of a mandatory voting system?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-a-mandatory-voting-system)

There are many countries where you are free to vote, but not free to choose to vote. How does mandatory voting affect the election process, and the country that requires it?