# Can compulsory voting increase the quality of a non-dictatorial republic democracy?

Tags: democracy, political-theory, voter-turnout

This is somehow a followup of [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/does-voting-really-matter-as-a-democrat-living-in-a-solidly-republican-state/) about vote meaningfulness.

According to [this article](https://phys.org/news/2014-09-liberal-countries-citizens-happier-individuals.html), "Overall, people living in countries with more liberal policies reported higher life satisfaction than those in countries with less liberal policies, irrespective of their own political views". So, I will define *democracy quality* to how *liberal* that democracy is.

By liberal, I am referring to the definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_democracy):

> [...] fair, free, and competitive elections between multiple distinct
>   political parties, a separation of powers into different branches of
>   government, the rule of law in everyday life as part of an open
>   society, and the equal protection of human rights, civil rights, civil
>   liberties, and political freedoms for all people.

I am also assuming a country with a fair amount of liberal democracy (like in most Western countries): multiple political parties, separation of powers, protection of human rights. So, dictatorships are ruled out.

To make things even more specific, I am talking only about countries that are considered liberal democracies according to [this source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_democracy#Liberal_democracies_around_the_world).

My assumption is that higher vote turnout correlates to the quality (as defined above) of the democracy. So, compulsory voting correlates to a high quality democracy.

I have an example from Romania:

- [Presidential elections in 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_presidential_election,_2014) - voter turnout 53% in the first round and 64% in the runoff. Result: a pro-EU, pro-NATO, pro-US, pro-fight against corruption president
- [Romanian legislative elections in 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_legislative_election,_2016) - voter turnout 39.5%. Result: the socialists with a satellite party have simple majority within the Parliament and start eroding the democracy by [decriminalizing official misconduct](http://www.dw.com/en/romania-decriminalizes-official-misconduct-amid-mass-protests/a-37361047).

A list of countries using compulsory voting can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_voting#Current_use_by_countries).

**Question:** can one assume that compulsory voting within a republic democracy is correlated with high quality democracy? Or are there too much factors to be taken into account to obtain a high quality democracy?

**[EDIT]**
I will try to improve the question by providing more examples. Using information from [here](http://www.parties-and-elections.eu/countries.html):

- [Liechtenstein](http://www.parties-and-elections.eu/liechtenstein.html), [Cyprus](http://www.parties-and-elections.eu/cyprus.html) and [Belgium](http://www.parties-and-elections.eu/belgium.html) have a form of compulsory voting and all seem to have a balanced Legislative
- [Romania](http://www.parties-and-elections.eu/romania.html), [Bulgaria](http://www.parties-and-elections.eu/bulgaria.html) and [Albania](http://www.parties-and-elections.eu/albania.html) do not have compulsory voting , and thus lower voter turnout and have polarized Legislative (one big party dominates the Parliament).

I could not find a top dealing with "how liberal a democracy is", but I could find [statistics for European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_statistics). The first three are better when it comes to freedom of the press, economic freedom and perception of corruption.

Comment: Not voting to close (for the moment), but please check if http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-a-mandatory-voting-system answers your question.

Comment: Does liberal here refer to the classical meaning of liberal(liberty loving) as opposed to the current popular meaning(progressive)

Comment: [North Korea has compulsory voting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_North_Korea)

Comment: @SoylentGray - I am referring to definition from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_democracy): "It is characterised by fair, free, and competitive elections between multiple distinct political parties, a separation of powers into different branches of government, the rule of law in everyday life as part of an open society, and the equal protection of human rights, civil rights, civil liberties, and political freedoms for all people."

Comment: So Classic Liberal not progressive

Comment: @endolith - Yes, indeed. Big exception to my assumed correlation. I will have to add another criteria for the correlation to make sense.

Comment: Also, I do not understand the example. 1) Apart from the "fight against corruption" item, this seems to imply that pro-EU/pro-US is good while anti-EU is bad, which is opinion-based. And 2) You seem to expect that compulsory voting would have changed the results; what is the base for that?

Comment: also compulsory voting kinda flies in the face of political freedom and civil liberties.

Comment: 1. I will check for references for this, as it is not opinion-based (at least not just my opinion). 2. I would have expected that no single party actually had a simple majority in the Parliament. Negotiations would have been required before any major law change.

Comment: Compulsory voting would seem to be against the *liberal* policies that you refer to. Thos governments with compulsory voting tend to be more likely to be dictatorships. You should give examples of countries with and without compulsory voting.

Comment: @sabbahillel - Australia is a definitive counter-example.

Comment: This question is not really answerable unless you define what a high quality democracy is (and of course note that your definition of a high quality democracy might be different than mine).

Comment: I don't see why it would. Compulsory voting doesn't improve the choices voters are given. We think of democracy far, far too narrowly. Voters need meaningful choices that appeal to them. If voter turnout is low, we shouldn't be forcing voters to the polls, we should seek to reengineer our electoral system to produce more attractive choices. The only thing that compulsory voting is sure to do is breed voter resentment.

Comment: In any given western democracy, fully half of the electorate is obsessed with free markets when it comes to trade. Why don't they ever seek to apply this model to their political system?

Comment: @JDoe - Yes, I have also been told about this in the past. But looking at the [party list from EU countries](http://www.parties-and-elections.eu/countries.html), in most of them there are plenty of choices. I do not know for other countries, but in Romania, for Parliamentary elections, one voter had more than 20 choices (parties and independent candidates). I think the list includes only parties that reached some threshold and the political offer is wider. It is hard to understand how one can be not satisfied by all of them.

Comment: It led to Cacareco, a rhino, to be elected mayor of sao paolo in 1959 http://hoaxes.org/archive/permalink/cacareco_the_rhinoceros

Comment: @Alexei Are these first-past-the-post countries, where each election can have only one winner? That creates a duopoly, where only two parties dominate to the practical exclusion of everyone else. There may be 20 choices, but only two are meaningful, and a vote for anyone else is considered "wasting your vote." This is what happens in the United States, which has many parties, but the same two always win virtually all of them.  It is called Durverger's Law.

Comment: The 2016 Presidential election is a great example. The two dominant parties produced two of the most disliked candidates in decades. In a working marketplace, other parties' candidates would attract more votes, and someone well-liked from another party would succeed instead. But that isn't what happens. Instead voter turnout is depressed severely. Compulsory voting would not have improved the likability of the two dominant parties' candidates, nor would it have helped a more likable candidate from another party, because voting for a third party is "wasting your vote".

Comment: @JDoe I think compelled voters following the same logic as traditional voters is doubtful. Mickey Mouse votes are not unheard of and I assume they are a form of protest and I'd guess they would increase with resentful voters. Getting people to sub in an un-electable guy for Mickey Mouse seems easier than getting them to switch from a contender.

Comment: @JDoe "two of the most disliked candidates in decades."  I'd say the problem is plurality voting. Cardinal voting systems would choose candidates with higher approval ratings, with no primaries required. and I know I'm starting a discussion in comments, but what is "a working marketplace"?

Comment: @endolith By a "working marketplace" I mean a system where vigorous competition among parties maximizes voter participation, voluntarily. Plurality voting doesn't do that. It preserves a duopoly that cannot fail competitively, but only through internal turmoil. We have been stuck with the same two dominant parties for 150 years, who routinely fail to attract 40% of voters (a plurality, incidentally, more than enough to compete with the duopoly) and yet who have successfully suppressed all competition for those votes, as no other parties have successfully emerged in all that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some jurisdictions do not recognize the results of (certain kinds of) elections if too few voters participate.  In these jurisdictions, voting is not compulsory; but not voting can affect the result.

There have been situations where the refusal of a large portion of the population to vote invalidated elections.  Such **non-** compulsory voting laws played a large part in the liberalization of Poland in the late-1980s, and helped end the Cold War.

In other countries, similar **non-** compulsory election laws can help ensure that tax referendums are voted on by a large fraction of the populace.  This prevents tiny minorities from holding quiet elections to impose taxes.  It increases the legitimacy of those taxes that are successfully imposed.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose we draw a numbered line, the numbers representing the number of citizens in a nation.  On the right side is the number of citizens, and we can put a dot there representing *voter compulsion* under which that number would also be the number of voters, **M**.  Just to the right of the middle somewhere, we might draw a dot representing the number of eligible voters who want to vote, **V**.  Somewhere to the left of that dot, we draw a dot representing the number of eligible voters who successfully vote and have their votes counted, **C**.  [Voter suppression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_suppression) equals **V - C**.

If we renumber the line, but keep the dots right where they are, and make **C < 0**, **V = 0**, and **0 < M**, it allows thinking of voter compulsion as sort of inverse function of voter suppression.

---

A partial and inductive answer is implied by a corollary question:  are democratic republics made *better* by aggressive voter suppression?

If voter suppression makes democracies *better*, then compulsory voting, (with zero voter suppression by default), would therefore tend to make them worse.

If voter suppression makes democracies *worse*, then compulsory voting, (with zero voter suppression by default), would therefore tend to make them better, because:

1. Those democracies would be free of that particular crime (voter suppression) and its many consequent national injuries.
2. The resultant vote would more completely reflect the will of the nation's voters in general, without being skewed by the will of any oppressive factions.

---

The above induction leaves out the possibility that the national gains made from the no longer suppressed voters (**V - C**) might not be offset by the remainder of citizens (**M - V**) who never voted being either dangerously ignorant or froward and voting accordingly.

Comment: Though it can be proven that A implies B, that does not imply that not A implies not B.

Comment: @DrunkCynic, agreed, which is why it's labeled a *partial* and *inductive* sort of  answer.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - However,  in propositional logic, according to [this source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(logic)): "It is the inference from the truth of "A implies B" the truth of "Not-B implies not-A", and conversely.". Of course, this is mathematics (logic), not politics.

Comment: Silliness. "to prevent the coercion of some people coerce every one" There are reasonable arguments for compulsory voting, but this isn't one.

Comment: @Alexei Valid points, though the rules of logical argument apply through out, particularly when you're making a logic based argument. In the last, it should be expected that those familiar with the application of logic will provide critical assessment.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt, Not quite, the direction of force is a necessary detail.  To abolish the crime of *negative* coercion to decisive majorities, apply *positive* coercion to all.

Answer (score -2):

> Question: can one assume that compulsory voting within a republic democracy is correlated with high quality democracy?

One certainly can but in my view it wouldn't be wise.

The only safeguard to any democracy is the quality of its voters. Not the quantity of its voters. Conceptually, compelling people to do anything they don't otherwise wishing to do hasn't turned out to be large scale success.  Obamacare being the latest example and I'm sure you can list out many more examples.

Comment: so you're suggesting that Germany is not a democracy? (or something along those lines)

Comment: Please clarify why merely choosing to vote makes a voter of quality.  If a good democracy ought to be filtering for quality, by similar principles, it might justify limiting voting exclusively to those with PhDs, or successful in business, (perhaps having a certain minimum income), or those who have won awards and badges in their fields.

Comment: @Federico I think he is suggesting that compulsory voting doesn't improve the quality of Germany's democracy. Germany has a decent quality democracy not because of compulsory voting but because of institutions that maintain the quality of its voters, in spite of compulsory voting. As I understand his argument.

Comment: @JDoe Germany does not have cumpolsory voting, but it has compulsory health insurance, something that apparently is equally bad, given this answer. I was trying to understand what makes that bad.